# Почему не могу запустить скомпилированый файл?

Tags: c++, g++

Здраствуйте,
написал небольшой код на С++, скомпилировал с помощью G++, при попытке запустить `a.out`
получаю ошибку
`[1]    53908 segmentation fault  ./a.out`

Сам код

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // for future 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int width = 130; // columns
    int height = 35; // lines

    char* screen = new char[width * height + 1];
    screen[width * height] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; i++)
        {
            float x = (float)i / width * 2.0f - 1.0f;
            float y = (float)j / height * 2.0f - 1.0f;
            char pixel = ' ';
            if (x * x + y * y < 0.5) pixel = '@';
            screen[i + j * width] = pixel; 
        }
    }
    printf("%s", screen);
    getchar();
    
}
```

Comment: char* screen = new char[width * height + 1]; перемудрили

Comment: почему перемудрили?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> for (int j = 0; j < height; i++)

Наверное имелось в виду

```
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
```